# .Net making of setup including solution,.net framework, crystal reports 2010, is it possible?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, installation

I wana made a setup or MSI Installer in .Net 4, which should install my C# project plus .Net framework 4 and crystal reports 2010 viewer. Right now, i have MSI Installer for my solution only and the two things are installed separately. But i want just one installer.

Please let me know any tutorial or best free solution.

Thanks
Atif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio lets you to make a simple setups, for example Sql Server needs very advance configuration like specifying instance name, SA user's password and so on ... doing this things in visual studio is impossible, yes you can chose to install them but you have to write some code to configure them in application start up.

You may find something [here](http://www.hlrnet.com/frprinst.htm)

Hope this help.

Comment: if i exec these other tools from codes, will it not be strange for a layman, i dont think it would look professional.

Comment: if not then you have to use commercial install maker such as Install Shield, Install Aware and etc or use none commercial product (which i'm not familiar with) It's completely depend what you need.

Comment: will install shield tackle these things?

Comment: I add a link above which contains a list of free setup maker.